# Create a column mostly with null data SQL like

Tags: database-design, relational-database

In postgresql I have a table with a list of cities. One row for city. Around 15000 rows. A column is `CITY_NAME`, now I have to add an english translation of the city name. The problem is that only 10 cities out of 15000 have an english translation.
I was thinking about two solutions:

1. Add a new column `CITY_NAME_ENG` with english translation, and keep the value to NULL for record without translation.
2. Duplicate the rows of the cities that have an english translation, keep only a column `CITY_NAME` and add a new column called `LANGUAGE`.

The second solution seems more elegant (and would be good if other languages will be add), but the select of all cities in a particular language seems tricky.

Are there other solutions? Which is better? NULL value occupy memory?

Comment: How likely is it that you will add another language later, and then another?

Comment: Good question. I suppose we will not add another language (surely not for the next 3 years).

Comment: "Add a new row CITY_NAME_ENG" - are you sure you're not confusing rows and columns?

Comment: @BohdanStupak you've right, I edited the post.

Comment: Am I correct that in the second approach you want to add the table with city name English localization?

Comment: No, but the solution is pretty similar. I think to keep only one table, with a column CITY_NAME (that can be in english or other language) and a new column LANGUAGE that wil be "ENG" or "ITA". This solution would be nearly equal to what you propose, to create a new table with CITY_ID, CITY_NAME and LANGUAGE, I suppose there is no real advantage in it.

Comment: "only one table ..  and a new column LANGUAGE that wil be "ENG" or "ITA"" - what if the city will have both names in English and Italian?

Comment: I will duplicate the row, for example the city of "Rome" will have a row with LANGUAGE "ITA" and the CITY_NAME="Roma" and another row with "ENG" and the CITY_NAME="Rome"

Comment: If there are more properties stored in this table, how would the software know that "Rome" and "Roma" refer to the same city and that an update needs to be applied to both rows?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau same CITY_ID, different LANGUAGE. The combination of both will be the new primary key.

Comment: @Accollativo: the problem with the "one table" approach is, when your program evolves and you will have to add new columns to a city which are independent from the translation (for example, number of inhabitants, area, or something like that), the same columns will automatically be introduced into the translation records. You end up having two places where this information could be stored, which has some risk of introducing errors or inconsistencies.

Answer (score 8):

A table called CityTranslations could be of help or more generically Translations.  Make a FK to the table that has the city column.

The table could have a column for the translation value and the language code.  Only have records for values that exist so you don't have a column with lots of NULL values.

Sounds like you would start with 10 rows and as more cities have translation value more rows could be added.

The translation table would have a a 1 to many relationship with parent table since each parent record could have multiple translations depending on how many languages are supported. A table with no translations would return no data.

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it.

Comment: This should be the correct solution but making a query to select all cities that have an English name otherwise if they have not, the Italian name, become slow and tough. Despite this should be the right solution I'm not sure it is in this case.

Comment: @Accollativo - I agree this isn't the best overall solution.   Usually with data, translations are not necessary.  For example "123 Main Street" would be "123 Main Street", regardless of language.  On the UI, if I had a label called "Address", that's what would be translated, usually in the form of some sort of resources file(s) on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that you're not planning to have a new translation for the next couple of years I prefer the first approach because it eliminates the need for inner join when obtaining English translation. Which in turn would be beneficial for performance.

In any case, I suggest you consider if localization could be made somewhere else. I.e. on the front-end side of your application. In case you're doing js on your front-end every mature js framework has localization mechanism. That would save you some precious calls to the back-end.

Comment: Database servers are **really** good at doing joins, i don't think avoiding them will lead to any worthwhile performance gains.